# Monotonic function which is not an order-embedding

Tags: order-theory

I wrote down this definition during the lesson:

Let $\langle P, \leq_P\rangle$ and $\langle Q, \leq_Q\rangle$ be two posets.

A function $f: P \rightarrow Q$ is

- monotonic, if $x \leq_P y \implies f(x) \leq_Q f(y)$;
- order-embedding, if $x \leq_P y \iff f(x) \leq_Q f(y)$.

Of course, an order-embedding is also a monotonic function but I'm trying to show a monotonic function which is not an order-embedding (and so far, I wasn't able to find one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ consist of two non-comparable elements, and let $Q$ consist of two comparable elements. Each of the bijections from $P$ to $Q$ is monotonic, and neither is an order-embedding. Thus, the two are not equivalent even for bijections.

Comment: Even smaller: let $|P| =2$ and $|Q|=1$.

Comment: @ASCIIAdvocate: I specifically wanted bijections, to demonstrate that even that added restriction could be met.

Comment: Let $P$ the empty (of order relations) poset on one element, and $Q$ the nonempty poset on the same element!

Comment: Brilliant! Put on the point.

Answer (score 1):

Round reals to integers. Any of the usual rounding functions (down, up, nearest) are monotonic but not order-embedding.

More brutally, take any constant function from one partially ordered set to another (such as the one-element poset).

Generalizing both examples, any order-preserving function from poset $P$ to a "smaller" poset $p$, such as a quotient of $P$, or a placement of that quotient into a poset with additional elements.  And/or additional relations.

Answer (score 1):

## Category-Theoretic Interpretation

The problem also has a nice category-theoretic interpretation as follows:

The **preordered sets** are precisely the **thin (small) categories**
 and the **monotone** functions are precisely the **functors** between such categories.

Moreover, functors between thin categories are **trivially faithful** on morphisms,
and an **order embedding** corresponds precisely to being **full** on morphisms,
while **injective/surjective** corresponds precisely to **injective/surjective** on objects.

Now, as in most of category theory, there's little to almost no relation between the behavior of a functor on objects to its behavior on morphisms and this remains the case also for functors between thin categories:

> Between thin categories, a functor may easily be injective but still fail to be full,
>   and conversely, a functor may easily be full but still fail to be injective!

The situation improves just a little if antisymmetry enters the game, namely:

> Between **partially** ordered sets; if a functor is full then it is injective.

*Proof:* $$F(x)=F(x')\implies F(x)\leq F(x')\leq F(x)\stackrel{F:\mathrm{full}}{\implies} x\leq x'\leq x\stackrel{X:\mathrm{POSET}}{\implies} x=x'$$